# How can I return a new table of results for every id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT campaigns.id AS team_campaign_id, teams.id AS team_id, teams.team_name, SUM(activity_records.points) AS team_total_points
FROM teams
INNER JOIN campaigns ON teams.campaign_id = campaigns.id
LEFT JOIN team_members ON team_members.team_id=teams.id
LEFT JOIN activity_records ON team_members.id=activity_records.team_member_id
WHERE teams.deleted = 0
AND IFNULL(team_members.deleted, 0) = 0
AND IFNULL(activity_records.deleted, 0) = 0
AND campaign.id = 1
GROUP BY teams.id
ORDER BY SUM(activity_records.points) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Which returns the team with the highest points in a given campaign, in this instance it is:

```
+------------------+---------+---------------+-------------------+
| team_campaign_id | team_id | team_name     | team_total_points |
+------------------+---------+---------------+-------------------+
|                1 |       2 | Workout Kings |               310 |
+------------------+---------+---------------+-------------------+
```

I want to return the above table for each `campaign.id` that exists in one go without having to manually change the value of `campaign.id`.

The reason for this is each high-scoring team's members points are doubled. So I need to double the points of every high-scoring team's members for each campaign that exists.

I tried to do something like:

```
UPDATE (
  SELECT campaigns.id AS team_campaign_id, teams.id AS team_id, teams.team_name, 
  SUM(activity_records.points) AS team_total_points
  FROM teams
  INNER JOIN campaigns ON teams.campaign_id = campaigns.id
  LEFT JOIN team_members ON team_members.team_id=teams.id
  LEFT JOIN activity_records ON team_members.id=activity_records.team_member_id
  WHERE teams.deleted = 0
  AND IFNULL(team_members.deleted, 0) = 0
  AND IFNULL(activity_records.deleted, 0) = 0
  AND campaigns.id = 1
  GROUP BY teams.id
  ORDER BY SUM(activity_records.points) DESC LIMIT 1
) AS top_team
SET top_team.team_campaign_id = top_team.team_campaign_id + 1;
```

But I get back `The target table top_team of the UPDATE is not updatable`.
Is this possible and any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Some tables and data they have**

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    campaign_id INT,
    team_name VARCHAR(50),
    team_size TINYINT,
    deleted BOOL DEFAULT 0,

    FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES campaigns(id),
    UNIQUE KEY campaign_team_id (campaign_id, team_name)
);

+----+-------------+------------------+-----------+---------+
| id | campaign_id | team_name        | team_size | deleted |
+----+-------------+------------------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |           1 | Fitness Fanatics |         5 |       0 |
|  2 |           1 | Workout Kings    |         5 |       0 |
|  3 |           2 | Super Saiyans    |         5 |       0 |
|  4 |           2 | Zumba            |         5 |       0 |
+----+-------------+------------------+-----------+---------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE team_members (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT,
    team_id INT,
    deleted BOOL DEFAULT 0,

    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id),
    UNIQUE KEY team_team_members_id (user_id, team_id)
);

+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | team_id | deleted |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
|  2 |       2 |       1 |       0 |
|  3 |       3 |       2 |       0 |
|  4 |       4 |       2 |       0 |
|  5 |       5 |       3 |       0 |
|  6 |       6 |       3 |       0 |
|  7 |       7 |       4 |       0 |
|  8 |       8 |       4 |       0 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE campaigns (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    company_id INT,
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    deleted BOOL DEFAULT 0,

    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies(id)
);

+------------+------------+------------+
| company_id | start_date | end_date   |
+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 | 2022-02-05 | 2022-03-06 |
|          2 | 2022-02-05 | 2022-03-06 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: what is the use of having a separate table for every campaign?

Comment: Please add the table definitions using `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` and some sample data to your question - as text. Thank you

Comment: @user253751 sorry should have included that, each highscoring team's members points are doubled. So i need to double to points of every highscoring team's members for each campaign that exists.

Comment: @Kendle I've included some data in the edit, let me know if this helps, thanks

Comment: That's good thanks. I have to get back to work. I'll look later.

Comment: @Zero-gamma And how would you do that? What is the code that you wish you could write?

Comment: @user253751 I have the code which doubles the points when I manually specify a `campaign.id`. If I remove the `campaign.id = 1` then it will double the point of only 1 team, the one that is the top scorer of every existing team irregardless of what campaign they belong to. 

If it's possible I want to write the code that doubles the points of a team member if they belong to the top team in a specific campaign and repeat that for each campaign that exists.

Comment: @Zero-gamma So I think what you want to do is: 1. In each campaign find the team with the most points. 2. Update the points of the members of the teams you found in step 1. Is that correct?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, just that! Almost like having `campaigns.id = campaigns.id + 1` to return results for every `campaign`.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas version 8.0.28